# Update Mapbox direction instructions while driving/walking + add direction indicator

Tags: geolocation, mapbox, directions

I'm building a web app to view featured walking routes in my neighbourhood.

1. User opens the app and sees all different routes.
2. App gets current location and checks for most nearby route.
3. App requests the route to one of my featured routes.

User can use the app to navigate to a marker from my featured route that is most nearby.

I'm working with the Directions Service which can give me a list of walking instructions like this:

[image: mapbox walking instructions]

I'm now trying to combine the directions with my current location. What is the best option to do this? I want to update the instructions based on my current location so for example if I head east on the Amstelkade I want to see the next instruction at the top. I came up with the following:

**Add GeolocateControl to Mapbox**

`let geolocate =  new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
  positionOptions: {
  enableHighAccuracy: true
 },
 trackUserLocation: true
})
map.addControl(geolocate);`

Put a listener on the geolocate change event and update starting place (origin) to get the latest direction instructions.

```
geolocate.on('geolocate', function(location) {
    currentLocation = location;
    setOrigin(location);
    setDestination(location);
});

function setOrigin(location){
  if(Object.keys(directions.getOrigin()).length === 0){
     directions.setOrigin([location.coords.longitude, location.coords.latitude]);
  }
}
```

I'm a little bit lost if this is a proper solution because in this way i'm making a lot of requests (could put a debouncer on the geolocate event though). Is there a better way to solve this and make it more user friendly?

Question 2: is it possible to add a direction indicator (blue beam of direction you're heading) to Mapbox like Google does?
[image: gmaps]

Thanks all!